# Multiple edit of a database table in one form

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, forms, user-interface

ok heres my problem.
I have a database table that i want to edit multiple rows by using one form.

I am looking for a way to be able to display a form in which i will be able to edit the rows and save the entries in a grid view kind of way.

Can this be done by dynamically letting the user choose which fields he wants to edit or provide an excel sheet kind of interface where changes are made and saved to this already existing database table.

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP, if you name the form fields as `nameoffield[]` they will arrive in the request back to the server as an array. Just make sure empty fields have some place holder when they get sent back to the server and just parse through them one by one performing updates/inserts as necessary.